# Condicionar while al no obtener resultados en consulta MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, while

Estoy intentando representar algunos datos de una BD mysql, el codigo funciona a la perfeccion mientras obtenga al menos 1 resultado en la consulta mysql, el problema es que al no obtener resultados en la consulta, me imprime la tabla sin contenido. Como puedo condicionar el comportamiento de while al no obtener resultados en la consulta, osea que no imprima la tabla. Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
<?php
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
?>
<tr>
            <td><div align="center"><?php echo ($fila['IdFactura'] );?></div></td>
            <td><div align="center"><?php echo ($fila['Tipo'] );?></div></td>
            <td><div align="center"><?php echo ($fila['Boca'] );?></div></td>
            <td><div align="center"><?php echo ($fila['Numero'] );?></div></td>
            <td><div align="center"><?php echo ($fila['Letra'] );?></div></td>
            <td><div align="center"><?php echo date("d-m-y", strtotime($fila['Fecha']));?></div> 
            </td>
            <td><div align="center"><?php echo ($fila['Obs']);?></div></td>
            <td> <div align="right">$ <?php echo number_format (($fila['Saldo']), 2, ',', '.');}?> 
            </div></td>
```

Comment: Observa que en:
* while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($$resultado)){
Tienes dos $$, sería:
* while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){

Comment: bien ahi, edite la pregunta fue un erro de tipeo el codigo esta bien escrito en mi php. Como dije mientras la consulta tenga al menos un resultado todo funciona perfecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

También puedes hacer uso del atributo `num_rows` para asegurarte de que tienes registros que mostrar. Simplemente tendrías que añadir la línea del `if` antes del `while`:

```
<?php
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

if($resultado->num_rows)
  while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio de mucho tu respuesta! Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Hice algunos cambios pero es prácticamente lo mismo, a mi este ejemplo me funciona, cambié el resultado a un array asociativo y en el if compruebo si la variable $resultado no está vacía, si no está vacía muestra todos los datos por el foreach, si esta vacía la variable $resultado muestra el mensaje "Tabla vacía".

```
<?php
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if(!empty($resultado) ) {
?>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>CampoTabla</th>
            <th>CampoTabla</th>
            <th>CampoTabla</th>
            <th>CampoTabla</th>
            <th>CampoTabla</th>
            <th>CampoTabla</th>
            <th>CampoTabla</th>
            <th>CampoTabla</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    foreach ($resultado as $fila) {
    ?>
        <tr>
        <td><div align="center"><?= $fila['IdFactura'] ?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?= $fila['Tipo'] ?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?= $fila['Boca'] ?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?= $fila['Numero'] ?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?= $fila['Letra'] ?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?= date("d-m-y", strtotime($fila['Fecha'])) ?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><?= $fila['Obs']?></div></td>
        <td><div align="right">$ <?= number_format(($fila['Saldo']), 2, ',', '.') ?></div></td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php } else { ?>
Tabla vacía
<?php } ?>
```

#### Nota:

La etiqueta:

```
<?= 'hola este es un mensaje' ?>
```

es igual a:

```
<?php echo 'hola este es un mensaje'; ?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Saludos

Answer (score 0):

mete la tabla en un if y cuenta las filas que te regresa la consulta y si es >0, imprimes la tabla.

```html
<?php
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_all($consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($resultado);
if($rows == 0) {

    echo "No hay datos";
} 

else
{
    ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>CampoTabla</th>
                <th>CampoTabla</th>
                <th>CampoTabla</th>
                <th>CampoTabla</th>
                <th>CampoTabla</th>
                <th>CampoTabla</th>
                <th>CampoTabla</th>
                <th>CampoTabla</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><div align="center"><?= $fila['IdFactura'] ?></div></td>
            <td><div align="center"><?= $fila['Tipo'] ?></div></td>
            <td><div align="center"><?= $fila['Boca'] ?></div></td>
            <td><div align="center"><?= $fila['Numero'] ?></div></td>
            <td><div align="center"><?= $fila['Letra'] ?></div></td>
            <td><div align="center"><?= date("d-m-y", strtotime($fila['Fecha'])) ?></div></td>
            <td><div align="center"><?= $fila['Obs']?></div></td>
            <td><div align="right">$ <?= number_format(($fila['Saldo']), 2, ',', '.') ?></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: gracias por la daa, pero como debería realizar eso?. Perdón estoy recién comenzando en php y mysql, mi nivel es prácticamente nulo a pesar de que vi varios manuales y tutoriales.